# Declaring an array of data elements so as to obtain scatter dot on the canvas

Tags: javascript, jquery, canvas

Consider this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h2yJn/1896/). Here I would like to declare a dataset so as to obtain scatter dots on the canvas.

```
 //   var data = [2,2],[3,3],[3,4]; // data to be declared

 var bw = 400;
 var bh = 400;

 var p = 10;

 var cw = bw + (p*2) + 1;
 var ch = bh + (p*2) + 1;
```

So as to obtain an output as below. How to achieve this ?

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write a function like this

```
function drawData(_data) {
  _data.forEach(function(elem){
    console.log(elem[0], elem[1]);
    context.beginPath();
    context.arc((elem[0]*40 + 10),(elem[1]*40 + 10),10,0,2*Math.PI);
    context.fill();
  });
}
```

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/h2yJn/1898/)

**EDIT FOR COLORS**

You can define an array for colors like

```
var colors = ["black","yellow","blue","red","orange"];
```

Then in draw function before `.fill` you can do

```
context.fillStyle = colors[elem[1]];
```

**[UPDATED FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/h2yJn/1899/)**

Comment: Batu Zet - Thank You, How to set different colors for scatter dots in different lines ?

Comment: Batu Zet - Thank you, but I would like to keep just two colors. If the dataset have same X value i.e [3,3] and [3,4] then they should have same color. If the preceding data value for this dataset with common X value is different then it should have different color(as in the image). How to do this ?

Comment: @user3438326 then you just need 2 colors in `array` and you can use `colors[elem[0] % 2]` for getting it. **[SEE THIS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/h2yJn/1901/)**

Answer (score 0):

1. Prepare a `location` array to store all the `x` and `y` information of cross section point. Something should look like this (Note that your respective x and y value should be corresponding with your pixel location at your `dashboard` crosee section point:

   var location = [{x:0, y:0}, {x:0, y:1}, {x:0, y:2}....];
2. Then you should have a function to draw a `canvas circle`: [learn how to draw a circle](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/tutorials/html5-canvas-circles/)
3. Then it would depand how you get the location you want to draw the circle.

*You can actually skip `1` and directly use `2`. But `1` is usefull where you can itenerate the index of array and access the `x` and `y` informations.